# After inputting an integer for a scanf() function, code does not continue?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

My objective is to create a program that checks if a specific bit (entered by the user) is set in a hard-coded integer (in this case 159). This code compiles, however when I enter my desired integer, the console stalls for about a second and then exits the program with no error message. None of the printf() functions are executed, as nothing else is printed out on the console before it exits. I'm fairly new to C, so I need some help with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 159;
    int position = 1;

    scanf("%d", position);

    if (position == 0) {
        position = 1;
        printf("if");
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            position *= 2;
        }
        printf("else");
    }

    printf("%d", position);

    if ((x & position) != 0) {
        printf("true");
    }
    else {
        printf("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a closer look at your book or tutorial about `scanf` and the arguments it expects. You need to pass *pointers* to the variables.

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` for this at all?  `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int position = argc > 1 ? strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1;...` Good rule of thumb for those learning C: don't use scanf until you understand the language.  It is not for the novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf function` takes `address` of variable like this `scanf("%d", &position);`

not variable itself.

it will place entered value in that address so you need to add `&` to your `scanf`.

and even after that. except when your position is `0` this code will never work:

```
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            position *= 2;
        }
        printf("else");
    }
```

this is an infinitive loop.It will execute until `position` become so large that `int` doesn't have enough space to store it so `position` become some illogical number like uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. As for the infinitive loop, I am aware that I must never put an argument variable into the for loop itself, however I am also an idiot. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: @MartinKiryakov Feel free.There is no need for thanks. If it really helped you, accept the answer.